# Wt with a Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, wt

I have a `Wt` application deployed at `www.sample.com:11000` (`http-address 0.0.0.0`), in dedicated process mode, using the built-in HTTP server (`-lwthttpd`). In the same server, I have a working `Apache2` installation.

I've never configured a reverse proxy before. I've read some tutorials about configuring reverse proxies with `Apache` but I've found nothing about `Apache` + `Wt`, and I don't fully understand how to do it correctly.

In short, I want to know how to configure my  `Apache` to serve as reverse proxy for `www.example.com:11000`, under `www.example.com:80`, and what `Wt` options I've to change to make the website works.

My server is an `Ubuntu 14.04 Server`.

**NOTE1:** Since Wt creates web apps, the page is never reloaded (it uses Ajax for everything), URLs are always relatives, and each session is a dedicated process with its own session id (carryied on each Ajax request).  The server is another process which uses sockets to speak with session processes. If the users closes the tab or travel to another website, the session is closed and the process is destroyed.

But! For things like OAuth and payment methods, where a redirect urls is mandatory, you must open a popup window in order the session isn't destroyed. For that, Wt also provides the concept of `resources`, which are mini-services, privates to a session. When you open the popup window, the redirection url is the url of that mini-service, which replies with a javascript function which closes the popup window. **That redirection url is, of course, absolute.**

**NOTE2**: The only option I know respect to the Wt documentation, is the following one:

`behind-reverse-proxy`
When enabling this option to indicate that the application is deployed behind a reverse proxy (as would be common if you use the `wthttpd` connector), the server location is not read from the `Host` header, but from the `X-Forwarded-For` header, if present.

How I ensure the `X-Forwared-For` header is always present?

Comment: The biggest problem could be that the backend server (your wt server) thinks it needs to write `www.sample.com:11000` into URLs in  pages it ships, otherwise, go with any of the generic tutorials and see if it works. A simple `ProxyRequests Off ProxyPass / http://localhost:11000/` might be enough.

Comment: AFAIK, Wt never uses absolute URLs in pages it servers. It uses always relative URLs. Anyway, I've added two notes to my post.